# Calculation of drug efficacy- mathematical biology approach

Tags: cancer, pharmacology, theoretical-biology

I am participating in a mathematical biology project.
I would like to discuss the following problem:

Let A be a drug such that $x_{o}$ chemical units of it kills 12% of $y$ cells per 1 day, I would like to calculate the efficacy killing rate of the drug.

My attempt:

**Duration of process:** 1 day

**Killing rate $r$ of cells by drug A:**

$$
\begin{aligned}
&100y e^{-r t}=12y \\
&100 e^{-r}=12
\end{aligned}
$$
so
$$
r=2.12 / d a y
$$

**Efficacy rate of drug A- meaning in which rate cells are killed
per 1 unit of drug A per 1 day:**
$$
\begin{aligned}
p x_{o} &=2.12 / \text { day } \\
p &=\frac{2.12}{x_{o}}\left[\frac{1}{U \cdot d a y}\right]
\end{aligned}
$$

Here $U$ means the chemical units of the drug.

Is it correct biologicaly/physically to decompose the a rate of process into the product of efficacy rate  and the initial amount of drug?
Is there anything wrong in thi process? another way of calculation?